# problemas ao validar hash com senha no php

Tags: php

Ao criar um usuário, faço o seguinte para `criptografar` a senha:

```
$options = ['cost' => 12];
$encripted = password_hash($this->input->post('senha'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

Ao realizar o login faço o seguinte:

```
$result = $this->db->get('users');
$db_password = $result->row(2)->senha;
if (password_verify($senha, $db_password)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Mas sempre cai no **FALSE**.

OBS: coloquei um `print_r` para verificar o valor da `db_password` traz o `hash` correto.

Comment: Parece estar normal, tenta usar o `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` como hash.

Comment: Não custa perguntar: verificou se o hash está sendo truncado no banco de dados, por exemplo, digamos que o campo do banco é varchar(50). No caso do algoritmo PASSWORD_BCRYPT são necessários 60 caracteres.

Comment: Nossa... pior... é isso mesmo... rapaz nem percebi isso.. rsrssr.. obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sua pergunta foi respondida no comentário, estou apenas reescrevendo e acrescentando maiores detalhes, caso alguém venha a ter o mesmo problema.

A função `password_hash()` possui dois algoritmos suportados, sendo eles:

1. PASSWORD_DEFAULT
2. PASSWORD_BCRYPT

O `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` usa, atualmente, o bcrypt. Ela é projetada para ser alterada quando novos algoritmos mais fortes forem implementados no PHP. Dessa forma atualmente ela exige 60 caracteres, porém é recomendado que armazene-a em colunas maiores. **O manual do PHP recomenda que armazenar numa coluna com 255 caracteres seria suficiente.**

Enquanto isso o `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` irá usar a função `crypt()`. Nela o resultado será sempre de 60 caracteres. Nesse caso não há intuito do PHP alterar isso, **portanto armazenar numa coluna de 60 caracteres é suficiente**. Lembre-se que caso use o `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` **a senha deve possuir no máximo 72 caracteres**.

*Não havendo espaço suficiente para ser armazenado, como no seu caso, irá resultar em erro.*

Veja o manual para mais informações: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php